# Calculating two numbers based on percentage of a given number

Tags: ratio

So I have two numbers one is the main number, lets say 53. I want to find two corresponding numbers automatically given that the two numbers should equal to 53 and have a gap of 10.4%. So let me do one example.

Original Number = 53.37 (Known)
Gap = 10.4 (Known)

First number = 28.15
Second number = 25.22
Gap between the two = (28.15-25.22)/ 28.15 (first number) = 10.4%
28.15 (First number) + second number (25.22) = 53.37 (original number)

I did this example by hand. Now I have a lot of other equations to solve like this. I want to do them automatically. E.g.
Original Number =264
Gap = 11.5

Original Number = 800
Gap = 12.5

Is there any way to do this automatically in excel? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is not a statistics question, but if the sum is $S$ and the gap is $g\%$ of the larger value then

- the larger value is $\dfrac{1}{2-\frac{g}{100}}S$
- the smaller value is $\dfrac{1-\frac{g}{100}}{2-\frac{g}{100}}S$

so in your example $\dfrac{1}{2-\frac{10.4}{100}}\times 53.37 \approx 28.15$ and $\dfrac{1-\frac{10.4}{100}}{2-\frac{10.4}{100}}\times 53.37 \approx 25.22$